# Explaining older sister sharing 1,961 cM as close family or 1st cousin

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

My older sister came back "close family-first cousin".

What does this mean?

Shared DNA 1961 cM across 74 segments

Answer (score 1):

[DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1961) says that 1961cM probably means one of the following:

- Grandparent
- Aunt or Uncle
- Half Sibling
- Niece or Nephew
- Grandchild

I'm guessing that you can rule out grandparent and grandchild :-)

Answer (score 1):

From [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 for 1,961 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1961) it would seem that you are more likely to be a half-sister or niece (your age difference may help distinguish which) than a full sibling.

Full sisters seems unlikely because at that page the expected range for full siblings is 2,209 - 3,304 with the mean at 2,629 cM.